# My database cannot be opened in VS Code, the file is not displayed in the editor because it is either binary

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-code

While I use .NET Core `update database` in terminal, it creates the database, but it cannot be opened and I cannot enter any data. I am using sqlite extension and it says file not displayed in the editor because it is either binary or uses an unsupported text.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

VisualStudio Code is unable to open a database in its entirety and output everything at once. Instead, you can use VisualStudio Code to connect to a database and then use Statments to extract data from the database.

**Use** `SELECT * FROM tablename` to output all table data.

However, you must execute this line with  programming language that you are using to connect to database!